# Combine multiple PSCP commands?

Tags: command, merge, pscp

I need to transfer multiple folders from my server to my pc. I'm currently using a command like:

```
pscp -r user@ServerIP:/public_html/folderA "C:\folderA" && pscp -r user@ServerIP:/public_html/folderB "C:\folderB"
```

The problem is that the above command is handled as 2 separate commands, requiring me to type the server password twice (once before the folderA command is executed and once before the folderB command is executed).

Is it possible to merge the commands in such a way, that the password is only required once?

Comment: you run it on linux ?

Comment: It's a linux server and I'm running PSCP via a Windows command prompt.

Comment: you may wish to install a key on unix account. if the key is password less, you will have no need for passwd, if you setup a passwd, you can use pageant to store the key and the passwd.

Comment: Okay, but does that mean there's no way to merge commands in such a way, that a password is only required once?

Comment: I am afraid not with pscsp, you can push multiple file/folder from local to remote, but no the other way round.